# Populate a table with data from MySQL table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu, html-table

I have a search box and a dropdown box. I am using these to filter data being displayed on my table from the MySQL table. I can type a county name in to the searchbox and all the records with that county name will be dsiplayed. THAT works fine, however my dropdown box is not working.

The dropdown box is displaying all the county names however when I click a county in the list only the records with that county should be displayed in the table. There are no errors being shown and the table remains unfiltered.

```
    <?php
require_once("includes/session.php");
include_once("includes/masterinclude.php");
$preferences = getPreferences();
$category = "";
$attribute1 = ""; $attribute2 = ""; $attriute3 = ""; $attribute4 = "";
$top_level="0";
$name = $_GET['member'];
$name = $_GET['counties'];
$information = getInformationPage($name);
$infopagename=$information->IN_NAME;
//meta data for information pages now taken from the information table
$pageTitle = $information->IN_NAME . html_entity_decode($information->IN_TITLE);
$pageMetaDescription = html_entity_decode($information->IN_META_DESC);
$pageMetaKeywords = html_entity_decode($information->IN_META_KEYWORDS);
$pageCustomHead = html_entity_decode($information->IN_CUSTOM_HEAD, ENT_QUOTES);
//initialise screen fields
$selected_member = "";
$id = "";
$username = ""; $username_original = "";
$password = ""; $password_original = "";
$password_test = "";
$title = "MR"; $first_name = ""; $last_name = ""; $company_name = "";
$address1 = ""; $address2 = ""; $town = ""; $county = ""; $country = ""; $postcode = ""; $phone = ""; $mobile = ""; $email = "";
$member_confirmed = "N";
$ast_first = 0; $ast_last = 0; $ast_company = 0; $ast_add1 = 0; $ast_add2 = 0; $ast_town = 0; $ast_county = 0; $ast_country = 0; $ast_post = 0; $ast_phone = 0;
$ast_mobile = 0; $ast_email = 0;
$ast_user = 0; $ast_pass = 0; $ast_passconf = 0;
$selected_product = "";
$members = Get_All_Members("ALL");
$counties = Get_All_Counties("ALL");
$_GET['searchdata'] = $_POST['SEARCH_DATA']; $_GET['searchmember'] = $_POST['MEMBER'];
$selected_county = $counties->CTY_COUNTY;
$_GET['searchdata'] = $_POST['SEARCH_DATA']; $_GET['searchcounty'] = $_POST['COUNTY'];
include_once("includes/header.php");
?>
<!-- start: Page header / Breadcrumbs -->
<div id="breadcrumbs">
<div class="container">
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="/">Home</a><i class="icon-angle-right"></i>Stockists
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end: Page header / Breadcrumbs -->
<!-- start: Container -->
<div id="container">
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<!-- start: Page section -->
<section class="span12">
<div class="row-fluid shop-result">
<div class="inner darken clearfix">
<h1>Stockists</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
$sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' ";
$sql .=" OR MB_COMPANY = '{$search_term}' ";
}
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="stockists.php">
<div class="row-fluid">
Search <input type="text" name="search_box" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search the stockists" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
</form>
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="stockists.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="all_counties" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)" type="submit">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT CTY_COUNTY FROM counties");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"stockists.php\">" . $row['CTY_COUNTY'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['all_counties']);
$sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' ";
$sql .=" OR MB_COMPANY = '{$search_term}' ";
}
$query2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr>
<td><strong>Company Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Website</strong></td>
<td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
<td><strong>Address</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['MB_COMPANY'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['MB_MOBILE'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['MB_PHONE'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['MB_ADDRESS1'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_ADDRESS2'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_TOWN'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_COUNTY'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_COUNTRY'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</section>
<!-- end: Page section -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end: Container -->
<?php
include_once("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_` functions - they're deprecated. Use `mysqi_` or `PDO` calls. Look into stored procedures too as they will make using variables from forms easier and more secure

Comment: Putting in mysqi just breaks all my code, so that's not very helpful.

Comment: @DaveyBoy You right !!
jonlloyd : As off simply you will add mysqli will not work and it will throw the errors only for using mysqli you are required to frame all the things in proper manner then only then it will work. Hope this tip will work for you.

Comment: please learn to indent, it makes debugging much easier.  If you expect some help, then its polite to present your code in a format that can be read easily.

Comment: My code is indented its just the way it has pasted. Indented below  ↓ ↓ ↓

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once("includes/session.php");
include_once("includes/masterinclude.php");

$preferences = getPreferences();
$category = "";
$attribute1 = ""; $attribute2 = ""; $attriute3 = ""; $attribute4 = "";
$top_level="0";

$name = $_GET['member'];
$name = $_GET['counties'];

$information = getInformationPage($name);
$infopagename=$information->IN_NAME;
//meta data for information pages now taken from the information table
$pageTitle = $information->IN_NAME . html_entity_decode($information->IN_TITLE);
$pageMetaDescription = html_entity_decode($information->IN_META_DESC);
$pageMetaKeywords = html_entity_decode($information->IN_META_KEYWORDS);
$pageCustomHead = html_entity_decode($information->IN_CUSTOM_HEAD, ENT_QUOTES);

//initialise screen fields
$selected_member = "";
$id = "";
$username = ""; $username_original = "";
$password = ""; $password_original = "";
$password_test = "";
$title = "MR"; $first_name = ""; $last_name = ""; $company_name = "";
$address1 = ""; $address2 = ""; $town = ""; $county = ""; $country = ""; $postcode = ""; $phone = ""; $mobile = ""; $email = "";
$member_confirmed = "N";
$ast_first = 0; $ast_last = 0; $ast_company = 0; $ast_add1 = 0; $ast_add2 = 0; $ast_town = 0; $ast_county = 0; $ast_country = 0; $ast_post = 0; $ast_phone = 0;
$ast_mobile = 0; $ast_email = 0;
$ast_user = 0; $ast_pass = 0; $ast_passconf = 0;

$selected_product = "";
$members = Get_All_Members("ALL");
$counties = Get_All_Counties("ALL");
$_GET['searchdata'] = $_POST['SEARCH_DATA']; $_GET['searchmember'] = $_POST['MEMBER'];

$selected_county = $counties->CTY_COUNTY;
$_GET['searchdata'] = $_POST['SEARCH_DATA']; $_GET['searchcounty'] = $_POST['COUNTY'];

include_once("includes/header.php");
?>

<!-- start: Page header / Breadcrumbs -->

<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumbs"> 
        <a href="/">Home</a><i class="icon-angle-right"></i>Stockists
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- end: Page header / Breadcrumbs -->


<!-- start: Container -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">

        <!-- start: Page section -->
        <section class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid shop-result">
                <div class="inner darken clearfix">
                    <h1>Stockists</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">

            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";

            if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

                $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

                $sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' ";

                $sql .=" OR MB_COMPANY = '{$search_term}' ";
            }
            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            ?>

            <form name="search_form" method="POST" action="stockists.php">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                Search <input type="text" name="search_box" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search the stockists" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            </form>


            <form name="search_form" method="POST" action="stockists.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <select name="all_counties" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)" type="submit">
                    <?php 
                    $sql = mysqi_query("SELECT CTY_COUNTY FROM counties");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    echo "<option value=\"stockists.php\">" . $row['CTY_COUNTY'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </form>


            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";

            if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

                $search_term = mysqi_real_escape_string($_POST['all_counties']);

                $sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' ";

                $sql .=" OR MB_COMPANY = '{$search_term}' ";
            }
            $query2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            ?>

            <table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Company Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Website</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
            </tr>

            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_COMPANY'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_MOBILE'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_PHONE'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_ADDRESS1'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_ADDRESS2'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_TOWN'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_COUNTY'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_COUNTRY'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </table>

        </section>

        <!-- end: Page section -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- end: Container -->

<?php
  include_once("includes/footer.php");
?>
```